# output of the function with the float pointer parameter and input as a address of int variable

Tags: c, pointers

I am very new to this topic `pointers` in C. I have one code as follow.

The output of this code is 0.000000 but i can't understand why so?

```
 void foo(float *);
    int main()
    {
    int i=10,*p=&i;
    foo(&i);
    }

    void foo(float *p)
    {
    printf("%f",*p);
```

Comment: May be undefined behavior?

Comment: @MikeCAT: No "maybe" about it. It *is* undefined.

Comment: the output is coming, instead of 10 its printing 0.0000 . i can't understand why it is undefined behavior if there any

Comment: You shouldn't pass `int*` to where they expect `float*`.

Comment: so it will make 10 to 0.0000 ???

Comment: In IEEE754 32-bit floating point number, `0x0000000A` stand for `1.4E-44`. Try using `%g` instead of `%f`.

Comment: Why do devs continually do obviously illegal things and then ask here why the result is unexplained?  'OK,so I drove my car into a tree, but why am I in hospital with all these broken bones?'

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's, yet again, some poster seeking to have an obviously illegal/incorrect/stupid operation explained.

Answer (score 0):

First check this [site](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_pointers.htm) to know pointer behavior.

In your code you declare float type parameter but pass integer value.

Try this one:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void foo(int *p)
    {
    printf("%d",*p);
    }


int main()
{
    int i=10,*p=&i;
    foo(&i);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It gives The below warning.

test.c:6:2: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘foo’ from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]

Because, you are passing the address to the foo function but expected argument is float *.
Then you are defining the p pointer as a integer type.

The variable p does not points the i.
But in foo function calling, there is no address is passed.

So, It gives warning and 0.0000.

So, change your code like below.

```
  void foo(float *);
    int main()
    {
    flat i=10,*p=&i;   //Change the data type
    foo(&i);
    }

    void foo(float *p)
    {
printf("%f",*p);
```

}

Now the output is

10.0000